# How to avail of `:hook` using use-package?

Tags: hooks, use-package

I've wrote this, and it works:

```
(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode (("\\.php$" .  web-mode)
         ("\\.html$" .  web-mode))
  :preface
  (defun dg/web-mode-hook())
  :config
  (add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'dg/web-mode-hook))
```

It enables `web-mode` when opening .php or .html files.
I've noticed that `use-package` also provides `:hook` directive, but it's not very clear how I can use it in this case.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks seems pretty clear to me, but maybe it can be further improved. Is that the documentation which you found confusing?

Answer (score 15):

As others said I think https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks
is pretty clear. `:hook` replaces `add-hook` and creates autoloads for
you. Your example with `:hook` would be:

```
(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode (("\\.php$" .  web-mode)
         ("\\.html$" .  web-mode))
  :hook (web-mode . dg/web-mode-hook)
  :config
  (defun dg/web-mode-hook()))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tought that `:hook` could some way save me from having to define a `my-hook-fn()`.

Comment: @Daniele, you should be able to use a lambda form:


    (use-package web-mode
      :ensure t
      :mode (("\\.php$" .  web-mode)
             ("\\.html$" .  web-mode))
      :hook (web-mode . (lambda () ...)))

Comment: It is not clear to me. For instance, couldn't you simply write `:hook dg/web-mode`, and if not, why?

Comment: @kotchwane if you click the readme link in the answer you see that if you pass only one argument (or a list of symbold), use-packages assumes those are the modes you want to activate your current "use-package package" if that makes sense. So in your case it would add `web-mode` to `dg/web-mode-hook` (the `-hook` is added by use-package)