# Calling org-indent-mode from org-mode hook causes infinite recursion?

Tags: org-mode, hooks

I have the following code in my emacs init files, and it is causing an infinite recursion, which eventually bottoms out and throws an error.

```lisp
(defun robs-org-mode-hook ()
  (org-indent-mode)
  ...)

(use-package org
  :init
  ;; ...
  :hook (org-mode . #'robs-org-mode-hook)
```

The stack if I run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`:

```lisp
org-mode()
run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
apply(run-hooks change-major-mode-after-body-hook (text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
run-mode-hooks(org-mode-hook)
org-mode()
run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
apply(run-hooks change-major-mode-after-body-hook (text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
run-mode-hooks(org-mode-hook)
org-mode()
run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
apply(run-hooks change-major-mode-after-body-hook (text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
run-mode-hooks(org-mode-hook)
org-mode()
run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
apply(run-hooks change-major-mode-after-body-hook (text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
run-mode-hooks(org-mode-hook)
```

Is there something wrong with that code, or is it a bug in emacs/org?

`M-x emacs-version` => "GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G9323))
of 2023-06-26"

`M-x org-version` => Org mode version 9.6.6 (release_9.6.6 @ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org/)

Comment: It's probably a bug in your setup. What is the value of `org-mode-hook` and `change-major-mode-after-body-hook`? Does this happen with `emacs -q -l /path/to/minimal/init.el` with  a minimal init that just has the `defun` and the `use-package` above?

Comment: Mmm. Weird. If I change `#'robs-org-mode-hook` to simply `robs-org-mode-hook`, then it all works fine. But with that `#'` (which I copied from online examples), then the value of `org-mode-hook` contains `org-mode`. Without it, then the value of `org-mode-hook` contains the `robs...` function, as expected. And this is with minimal startup init code, as you suggested.

Comment: OK - that's probably worth opening an issue against `use-package`. The examples at  the [use-package repo home page](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks) use just the symbol for the function, so the `use-package` macro must do something weird with the quoting, but it should probably protect against this kind of misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

[The OP has already answered his question in a comment above, but I dug a little to understand what was going on.]

As the OP points out in a comment:

```el
(use-package org
    :hook (org-mode . foo))
```

works fine.

You can use `macroexpand` to see what the macro expands to:

```el
(pp (macroexpand '(use-package org :hook (org-mode . foo)))) ===>
(progn
  (defvar use-package--warning8
    #'(lambda (keyword err)
    (let
        ((msg
          (format "%s/%s: %s" 'org keyword
              (error-message-string err))))
      (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (progn
    (unless (fboundp 'foo) (autoload #'foo "org" nil t))
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'foo))
    (error (funcall use-package--warning8 :catch err))))
```

As you can see, the function `foo` is added to `org-mode-hook` and everything is fine. But if you try the original form the OP used:

```el
(pp (macroexpand '(use-package org :hook (org-mode . #'foo))))
(progn
  (defvar use-package--warning9
    #'(lambda (keyword err)
    (let
        ((msg
          (format "%s/%s: %s" 'org keyword
              (error-message-string err))))
      (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (progn
    (unless (fboundp 'org-mode) (autoload #'org-mode "org" nil t))
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-mode)
    (add-hook 'function-hook #'org-mode)
    (add-hook 'foo-hook #'org-mode))
    (error (funcall use-package--warning9 :catch err))))
```

you can see *three* hooks are modified and they are modified incorrectly.

Part of the explanation is that `#'foo` is shorthand for `(function foo)` and if you try to macroexpand `(use-package org :hook (org-mode . (function foo)))` you get the same expansion as for `#'foo`.

The problem is that the expression `(a . (b c))` is equal to the list `(a b c)`, so when `use-package` sees `(org-mode . (function foo))`, it sees the same thing as if you had said `(org-mode function foo)` and interprets that as needing to set *multiple* hooks - see the second paragraph of section [Hooks](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks). Notice that there is no such thing as `function-hook` or `foo-hook`, but `add-hook` creates the variables if they don't exist already (do `C-h f add-hook` and read the doc string). They don't do any harm here because nobody uses them. But setting `org-mode-hook` to `org-mode` is indeed fatal.

The remaining question is: why are the three hooks (one real, two manufactured by `use-package`) set to `#'org-mode`, rather than to `nil` say?  I don't know the answer to that; I would have to go through the guts of the macro and given that I don't use `use-package`, I will leave it at that.

As I suggested in a comment, it is worth opening an issue on the `use-package` [Github site](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). You might also let the people who provided the online examples that you copied, know that they should fix their code.

---

*EDIT*: In a comment to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39261/14825) it is stated that "...if you pass only one argument (or a list of symbols) [as the value of the `:hook` keyword], `use-package` assumes those are the modes you want to activate your current 'use-package package'...". Although the description is not quite clear, I take it to mean that if you don't specify a function to add to the list of hooks (as in this case), it will take the name of the package you are setting up (`org` in this case), tack a `-mode` afterwards (`org-mode` in this case) and use *that* as the function. If that is indeed the case (and after some rudimentary checking, it seems that that is indeed the case), that would explain the above results, but it seems a somewhat bizarre interpretation by `use-package` of what the user wants to do.

It is also stated in that comment that the [use-package Github page](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) documents the above behavior, but I failed to find any reference to it. Caveat emptor.